# Get letters from string swift

Tags: swift

I want to get all letters into an array from the string.
Suppose I have string which contains letters and numeric then I want to get only all letters of the string.

```
let myString = "so123han"
```

Then output should be in array like this:

```
let arrayOfLetters = ["s","o","h","a","n"]
```

Comment: Have you even tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
let myString = "so123han"
let alphaChars = myString.unicodeScalars.filter({ CharacterSet.letters.contains($0) }).map({ Character($0) })
```

Comment: This doesn't give you an array of strings.

Comment: You're missing `import Foundation`. Also missing a call to `.map { String($0) }`.

Comment: You are right @DennisVennink thank you, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this!!

```
let myString = "so123han"
var arr = [String]()

for i in myString.unicodeScalars{
    if CharacterSet.letters.contains(i){
        arr.append("\(i)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would someone down vote this answer? There's nothing wrong with this answer.

Comment: I also don't know:(